# Make an Input act liked a Class

Tags: python, string, class, input

I have created a class say for eg. `fruit`. And I have made preset classes for example.

```
Apple = Fruit("Apple","red","small")
```

so where I can do `Apple.color` so that it returns red.

How can I ask the user for a `fruit` and it would be linked to the class?

```
my_fruit = input("Choose a fruit.")
my_fruit = Apple #but only as a string
```

How can I make `my_fruit.color` return red, similar to the created class of Apple. Would I need to convert this as a strong to a class?

Comment: What does the user input to get Apple? Are there other kinds of apples that can be created like `Fruit("Apple", "green", "medium")`?

Comment: the intention would only be to have one type of apple. Other options would be other fruit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, the following would work as I believe you intend:

```
class Fruit(object):

    def __init__(self, name, color, size):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.size = size


Apple = Fruit('Apple', 'red', 'small')

fruit_class = input('Choose type of fruit: ')
print(fruit_class.color)
```

However, the function `input` in Python 3 behaves like `raw_input` does in Python 2. The is no function in Python 3 like Python 2's `input`. However, effectively the same functionality can be achieved using `eval(input())` in Python 3 as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x).

The code would look like this:

```
Apple = Fruit('Apple', 'red', 'small')

fruit_class = eval(input('Choose type of fruit: '))
print(fruit_class.color)
```

However, use of `eval` is dangerous as the user can execute arbitrary code against the system. A mapping between the input string values you expect and the user to input and the class instances to which they should map could serve the same use case. For example:

```
Apple = Fruit('Apple', 'red', 'small')

fruits = {
    'Apple': Apple,
}

fruit_class_type = input('Choose type of fruit: ')
print(fruits[fruit_class_type].color)
```

Comment: the first example cannot work, but the last is better. you should even use `fruits.get(fruit_class_type, 'no fruit like this')` to set a default value

Comment: The first example _does_ work in Python 2. The second is a reproduction of the first in Python 3. And yes, agreed, there are many ways to improve upon input gathering and fall-through cases in the last example

Comment: I will run some tests to make sure that this allows me to pull the correct information from the class but this passed the initial tests. Thanks for the help, Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

**Creating an istance of a class through input**

I wish this code is what you intended. I understood that you wanted to create an istance of a class Fruit with attributes for color etc. with the input function. So I think this could be a possible solution.

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, type, color, size):
        self.type, self.color, self.size = type, color, size


fruit1 = Fruit(
    input("Choose a type of fruit: "),
    input("Choose the color: "),
    input("Choose the size: "))

print("This is your fruit:")
print(fruit1.type, fruit1.color, fruit1.size)
```

> OUTPUT
>
> ```
> Choose a type of Fruit: Ananas
> Choose the color: orange
> Choose the size: big
> This is your fruit:
> Ananas orange big
> ```